# MongoDB filter docs on dynamic key and value using regex

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have multiple fields in a document whose key value I don't know(only the user who has added the keys know that)

Now suppose user wants to finds a document specifying the key value, but he forgot what his key value was EXACTLY

So say I have this document:

```
name: "John Doe"
class: 5
MisChief: "Bullying"
```

where the MisChief key was custom created.

Suppose user wants to search for 'mischief: bullying'

I can use `$regex` operator to search for the value, but **how can I specify the key as a regex expression**?

Another way to do this is to return all documents, and doing a case insensitive search for the keys from all those documents which is very inefficient.

Comment: A regex expression for matching "Bullying" is simply `/Bullying/` https://regex101.com/r/wL1UZx/1

Comment: @terrymorse Yes you're right, but I want to achieve something like this:

`/mischief/i : /bullying/i`

Comment: Have you tried `/mischief : bullying/i`? That will match "MisChief: Bullying". https://regex101.com/r/BzODbK/1

Comment: So in MongoDB it would be ideal if your key names are *static*, You can't query against dynamic/unknown key names something like `db.collection.find({unknownKeyName : someInpuValue})` doesn't work, So you need to use MongoDB's aggregation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with unknown/dynamic/random key names, one way to do it using aggregation operator `$objectToArray` :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Add a new array field to all docs which contains each field as {k:...,v:...} */
  {
    $addFields: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } }
  },
  /** Match docs that has an object in `data` array which matches with input */
  {
    $match: { "data": { "$elemMatch": { "k": "MisChief", "v": "Bullying" } } } // can be a regex /MisChief/i
  },
  /** Remove added array field from output */
  {
    $project: { "data": 0 }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qeFHSAzULmk)

**Ref :** [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

From your statement :

```
but he forgot what his key value was EXACTLY
```

If he vaguely remembers Key name/value but doesn't remember it completely - You can do it using regex as you wanted ! But if he forgets it entirely 
then you can't do much just get all docs where `data.v : 'Bullying'` & use `$match` stage to filter further on `name` of user.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } }
  },
  {
    $match: { "data": { "$elemMatch": { "v": "Bullying" } } } 
  },
  {
    $project: { "data": 0 }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8xnPj0ZWe9O)

**Note :**

For one single element `{ "v": "Bullying" }` we don't need to use `$elemMatch` but to keep syntax consistent we're using it, otherwise you can just use `data.v : 'Bullying'` in `$match` stage.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly!! One thing I noticed is that in playground, the shorthand `/.*/i` regex expression doesn't work properly in the match stage, but it works when `$regex` operator is used. I used the shorthand in compass though and its working perfectly!

Comment: @jasondoyle121 : Yes playground doesn't support everything - mainly `/ /` (it's an open source option helpful only in few cases), As you said or did you can test it on DB itself :-)

Comment: Sorry I forgot about it completely, my bad!